# Javascript Typing animation that only affects a #div and allows HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've been thinking of using a plugin and, thanks to the nature of the site I use it on, I don't really have access to the  tag. And the site doesn't really seem to allow certain javascript. The only real javascript I've seen work is this:

```
var text = "Lorem Ipsum. Enter text here. Blabla blee blah blah. This is just stuff, but I have entire paragraphs to put here.";
var counter = 0;
var speed = 150;

function type(){
    lastText = document.getElementById("console").innerHTML;
    lastText+=text.charAt(counter);
    counter++;
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = lastText;
}

setInterval(function(){type()},speed);
```

HOWEVER, there is one gigantic flaw here. It would seem that could does not HTML coding such as `<span>`, `<br />` or `<p>`, which I use extensively as well as the ' character.

**My question is this: how do I make it so as to allow HTML?**

Perhaps even more ideal would be to have it do the same effect, but have the text in the BODY element where it belongs and not in `<script>`, but this isn't within the scope of my question currently, and I'd rather have the bolded question answered first, or if the script refuses to work on the site I'm coding at.

Comment: Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cug0tc35/

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve and what this script does.

Comment: Do you want to allow HTML tags to be entered as well?

Comment: He's looping through each character in a string, which works fine, but it will print raw HTML instead of actual HTML - see my demo, should make it obvious.

Comment: Yes, Nips, otherwise it shows up as one giant paragraph. As the code states. I'd like paragraphs and spans for styling. And I did clarify the question in bold. What I know is the current code, as is, works on the site I'm putting this on. However the div I have in mind has styling within spans, line breaks, etc. that javascript won't parse.